# How to insert for loop in database using datagridview data

Tags: vb.net

[Hi guys please help me what code will i use to save the data's inside the datagridview to my database in save button?

Thank you very much!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQmpx.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
If dgv.IsCurrentCellInEditMode = True Then
    MsgBox("Please exit edit mode and try again.")
    Exit Sub
End If
Execute("DELETE FROM tblSample;")

Dim c As Integer = 0
Dim dgv As Integer = dgv.Rows.Count - 1
While c < dgv
    Execute("INSERT INTO tblSample VALUES (" + dgv.Item(0, c).Value.ToString + "," + dgv.Item(x, c).Value.ToString + ");")
    c += 1
End While
fillDatatable(xDT, "SELECT * FROM tblSample;")
dgv.DataSource = xDT
dgv.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
dgv.Refresh()
MsgBox("Changes Applied!")



Public Sub fillDatatable(_datatable As DataTable, Query As String)
    Dim sqlQuery As String = (Query)
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(yourConnectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn)
            da.Fill(_datatable)
        End Using
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

This assumes you have an "Execute" method to Execute SQL queries. 
(tblSample = your table)
(dgv = your datagrdview) (x = row number (0,1,2,3...)) it uses a datatable as a temporary "save point" for data, not the most efficient, but it should work. hope it helped! xD

Comment: Parametise your query, bro.